# Parameter sets - how do I make the default work?

Tags: function, powershell, parameter-sets

I'm writing a function that updates a *.CSV file to be picked-up by a puppet script that will update a DNS Zone. Since I don't want to break the **real** .CSV file, I've added a dummy-file. While I'm developing this function, I have three parameter sets: `Reset`, `Add`, and `Remove`. These parameters will overwrite my dummy file with the current canonical .CSV file, add a record, and delete a record, respectively. The main script will never call the function with two or all three of these switches active.

Here's how I've coded my script's parameter block:

```
function Update-DNS_Dev
{
    [CmdletBinding(defaultparametersetname='Reset')]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0,
                   ParameterSetName='Reset')]
        [switch]$Reset,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            Position=0,
            ParameterSetName='Remove')]
        [switch]$Remove,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
            Position=0,
            ParameterSetName='Add')]
        [switch]$Add,

        # Name of a Dummy file
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=1)]
        [string]$DummyFile = "{0}\dPvmnames.csv" -f $DNSScratchpad,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ParameterSetName='Remove')]
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ParameterSetName='Add')]
        [string]$servername,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ParameterSetName='Add')]
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ParameterSetName='Remove')]
        [string]$domain,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ParameterSetName='Add')]
        [string]$details,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                    ParameterSetName='Add')]
        [string]$type
    )
}
```

Lower in the script, I use `switch ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName)` to process the switches' various functionalities. When I do a `Get-Help Update-DNS`, I see expected output:

```
PS> get-help Update-DNS_Dev

NAME
    Update-DNS_Dev

SYNTAX
    Update-DNS_Dev [-Reset] [[-DummyFile] <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Update-DNS_Dev [-Remove] [[-DummyFile] <string>] [-servername <string>] [-domain <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Update-DNS_Dev [-Add] [[-DummyFile] <string>] [-servername <string>] [-domain <string>] [-details <string>] [-type <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

When I invoke the function and supply the `-Reset` parameter, my script executes as expected, but if I invoke it without any parameters, my default does not take effect, and hitting `1`, `$true`, `true`, or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to accept what appears to be the default `-Reset` parameter always throws a red error message:

```
PS> Update-DNS_Dev 
cmdlet Update-DNS_Dev at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Reset: 

Update-DNS_Dev : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Reset'.
Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.
SwitchParameter". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers,
such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-DNS_Dev
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Update-DNS_Dev], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Update-DNS_Dev
```

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can get my function to take the `-Reset` switch default if the code calling the function does not supply any parameters?

Comment: Do not make `-Reset` mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would normally encourage `[Switch]` parameters to be mandatory when they define a parameter set, in your case you can't have it that way, and as PetSerAl said you must make it optional.

The reason comes down to what `Mandatory` actually means. It doesn't mean only that it must have a value, it means that the parameter must be *bound* as in, supplied by the caller. This is the same reason why giving a default value to a mandatory parameter doesn't work.

Comment: I thought of that very thing this morning in the shower. As soon as I got to work, I tested it.... Success!